# How to add read permission to Google Drive file for multiple users in one request

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm trying to insert 3 users as readers of a file on Google Drive and Google Docs using the API here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

However, this only allows inserting 1 user at a time so I'm currently waiting for the first request to finish before sending the next one.

Is there a way to insert multiple users in one request (using an array to store the users for example)?

I've looked at the `/batch` endpoint here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/batch, but I'm not sure how to use it or if that's what I need. I want to implement this in jQuery, but the example in the link only shows the request details but not any code.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wait for each request to finish before sending the next one? There is no reason why they can't be sent in parallel.

Comment: @pinoyyid I'm using the API here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert there's a warning: Concurrent permissions operations on the same file are not supported; only the last update is applied.

Comment: when I try adding read permissions for 3 users on the same file with parallel requests, I'm getting a 500 response code on 2 of the requests

Comment: You are right. My bad.

Comment: V3 has an example of using batch permissions here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to add multiple permissions in a single API request.  Batching requests still uses multiple API calls but does them all as a single HTTP request.  If that is what you want, it's something that the client library has to support.

You can see an example in Google's client library here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch